# Warning when import kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6

I've installed Python Kivy library on Windows using cmd and pip commands, but when I import it in IDLE, there is something wrong with that:

```
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Hadi\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-01-28_3.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
>>>
```

what's the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: What is wrong there? You're running a command and some debug information is printed, but I don't see an obvious error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error.

[INFO   ][Logger   ] = where you can find a .txt file recording all of your error reports on code execution failures.

[INFO   ][Kivy] = what version of Kivy you are developing with (the minimum requirement of kivy version required to run your application)

[INFO   ][Python] = what version of Python you are developing with (possibly the minimum requirement of Python required to run your application)

This is helpful because if I was to run your code on my computer and it fails to run properly then I would be able to see that i have Kivy 1.9 not 1.10 which it requires and Python 3.5 not 3.6 installed (for example)

NOTE ----:

you may want to include at the top of your code

```
Kivy.require('1.10.0')
```

Using this line will allow kivy to inform a user on an older version that they should probably update to this version or higher.
Using this line without a code failure will also confirm that your Kivy is not reporting an error and is working as intended.